# Show only direct subheadings with todo states

Tags: org-mode

is it possible to show only direct subheadings (children) of a subtree, that have any todo state?

I tried the function `org-show-todo-tree` which shows a list of all subheadings with a todo state no matter how deep they are nested.

And I tried the function `org-show-children`, which displays all the children, but also those with a `DONE` keyword.

But if I runt both functions in sequence one overrides the other. This means I either get only todos or only direct children, not only direct children that are todos.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are talking about searching in a file, not in the agenda, try this function at the top of the subtree you want to search:

```el
(defun my-sparse-subtree-todo-search ()
  (interactive)
  (org-narrow-to-subtree)
  (let ((level (org-current-level)))
    (org-match-sparse-tree  t (format "+LEVEL=%d" (1+ level)))))
```

Doing `M-x my-sparse-subtree-todo-search RET` should find all the TODO entries one level down in the current subtree. Very (ahem!) sparsely tested.

Comment: This is a big step towards the solution! Only `my-sparse-subtree-todo-search` expands headings with todos, while `org-show-children`neatly folds everything but the heading. This would be the desired result of this focussing operation. _Btw: If you consider sharing your config, I would be very interested :-)_

Comment: Additional to what Nick wrote, I am using configuration which is http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html also stuck-project part shows what you want.